# Imprimir no php papel customizado

Tags: php

Como posso configurar um tamanho de papel no php? por exemplo: tenho um papel de 140mm x 160mm.

Comment: Tem certeza que está usando a tag certa? Em princípio, PHP não tem funções elaboradas de impressão. Se possível, clique em editar e dê mais detalhes, por favor. Se estiver falando disto: http://php.net/manual/pl/ref.printer.php, é bom acrescentar na pergunta - se está usando alguma outra tecnologia, é bom mencionar também.

Comment: @Bacco, há alternativas como postei na minha resposta e usam PHP, mas eu acho que ele poderia incluir tags de css e html...

Answer (score 4):

Uma dica, sempre que enfrentei o problema usei alguma biblioteca para gerar arquivos PDF, [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) é velhinha mas resolve esses problemas.Ela vai gerar o PDF do tamanho do papel que você precisa.
Um exemplo mínimo

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');
//aqui vc personiza o tamanho do papel
$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm',array(140,160));
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Outra opção é [DomPdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) (converte html em pdf)

```
// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');
$customPaper = array(0,0,140,160); //personaliza aqui
$dompdf->set_paper($customPaper);
```

Eu prefiro a FDPF por ser mais rápida